# Why Client listener is giving the IP Address of the network Gateway?

Tags: listener, gateway

Why Client listener is giving the IP Address of the network Gateway?

[Client listener return IPaddress of the network gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NODO.png)

Comment: Because only the gateway's IP is known to the outside world?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code - copy and paste as text here. It is kind of rude to expect people here to re-type your code when answering your problems.